# "$ docker build -t docker-whale ." throws an error saying "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored or old ones used instead."

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I am trying to follow the official documentation given by Docker. When I try to build my own image as shown here "https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/"

I get the error message

> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
>   The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes' returned a non-zero code: 100"

This is what the docker.log file shows

time="2017-02-17T12:09:51.222171243+05:30" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]" 
time="2017-02-17T12:09:51.222255579+05:30" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers : [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]" 
time="2017-02-17T12:09:53.358000795+05:30" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]" 
time="2017-02-17T12:09:53.358065387+05:30" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers : [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"

Also, I checked the resolv.conf file in my system and it has one line "nameserver 127.0.1.1" which on further reading I understood is a IPV4 address and not IPV6. May be this info can be of help.

Any help to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Try running it with `--no-cache`, like this:

```
docker build --no-cache -t docker-whale .
```

If this does not help try to explicitly remove the apt list files, during the build, by adding the following to your *Dockerfile*

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
...
```

Comment: I tried using the same --no-cache . But the problem is not yet solved.

Comment: @Ragini would you please cut-and-paste the full Dockerfile, you are using

Comment: On trying this, I get a couple of more warning messages like these. "Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/… Hash Sum mismatch" along with the error message "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes' returned a non-zero code: 100" Also I tried to remove the apt list files not using the dockerfile but directly from the terminal and looks like I am not able to delete them because of the permissions.

Comment: Here's the dockerfile i am using
    FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay

Comment: The Dockerfile looks good to me, please try to build it again with `docker build --no-cache -t docker-whale .docker build --no-cache -t docker-whale .` and attach a full error log to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I could find the solution to my problem using the suggestions given here.

https://serverfault.com/questions/642981/docker-containers-cant-resolve-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop-host

I had to install the network bridge and restart docker like shown here to fix the problem with building my image.